# Create multiple rankings and a table

Tags: ms-access

Here is my problem: I am using SQL for Access 2013; I have a table `tbl` with some fields `Category`, `Subcategory` and `Value`:

```
Category  |  Subcategory   |  Value
          |                |
   C1     |      Sc1       |    x1   
   C2     |      Sc3       |    x2   
   C1     |      Sc2       |    x3   
   C3     |      Sc7       |    x4 
   C1     |      Sc1       |    x5   
...
```

Each category includes a unique set of subcategories, such that subcategories are not repeated between categories. However, subcategories can be repeated within a category (see for example first and last line from `tbl` above, where `Sc1` is repeated).

I would like to retrieve, for each category, the top 10 subcategories by total `value` and create a table `tblRankings` like this:

```
   C1    |   C2   |   C3   | ...
         |        |        | ...
 Top1,1  | Top2,1 | Top3,1 | ...
 Top1,2  | Top2,2 | Top3,2 | ...
 Top1,2  | Top2,3 | Top3,3 | ...
...
```

The basic query `qryRankingC1` for selecting the top 10 subcategories for a given category (in this case `C1`) based on total value is:

```
SELECT TOP 10 [Subcategory] AS C1
FROM tbl
WHERE [Category]='C1'
GROUP BY [Subcategory]
ORDER BY SUM([Value]) DESC;
```

However, once I have done this I am blocked; I have tried the following query to create the table:

```
SELECT qryRankingC1.* INTO tblRankings
FROM qryRankingC1
```

However this can only handle one category at a time. I would like to create a table with as many columns as categories in a single query if possible.

Moreover, instead of having `qryRankingC1`,`qryRankingC2`,... I would like to have a single `qryRanking` query, however if I do:

```
(SELECT TOP 10 [Subcategory] AS C1
FROM tbl
WHERE [Category]='C1'
GROUP BY [Subcategory]
ORDER BY SUM([Value]) DESC)
UNION
(SELECT TOP 10 [Subcategory] AS C2
FROM tbl
WHERE [Category]='C2'
GROUP BY [Subcategory]
ORDER BY SUM([Value]) DESC);
```

I get the top 10 subcategories for `C1` and `C2`, but on a single column named `C1`.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: `TRANSFORM` will [do what you want in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546305/pivoting-data-in-ms-access)